# Query regarding running JBOSS EJB in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, jboss, ejb

Is it possible to run JBOSS EJB in Apache Tomcat?

I am trying to do it. But I am getting marshalException. I am using a jar file of a JBOSS EJB Project for completing some action of the Tomcat project . I am not allowed to change the JAR files. Only thing I can do is to find a way to run that EJB in my tomcat.

First all I have to know is it possible?

Comment: `EJB` can deploy only on application server like JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere, not on web server/web container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache tomcat and JBOSS both are different thing apache-tomcat is web server and jboss is application server you can not integrate your Jboss EJB with apache tomcate this is not possible.ya but vice verse is possible you can integrate Apache tomcat with JBOSS.

**1 JBOSS - Application Server**

**2 Apache Tomcate - Webserver**

you can do some stuff with your JBOSS such that you can use Apache tomcat With JBOSS

and [this  link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/35017?start=60&tstart=0&_sscc=t) will help you to know more things about ot